# What is the problem in the code to synchronize parent and child process using semaphores?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, semaphore, critical-section

I wrote a C program to synchronize parent and child process using semaphores.

Here is the implementation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<fcntl.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int pid, n=-1;

        sem_t *p, *c;

        p = sem_open("/parent_semaphore", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
        c = sem_open("/child_semaphore", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);

        pid=fork();

        if (pid==0)
        {
                while (1)
                {
                        sem_wait(c);
                        n=rand();
                        printf("Child set value of n as %d \n", n);
                        sem_post(p);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                while (1)
                {
                        sem_wait(p);
                        if(n!=-1)
                                n=-1;
                        printf("Parent reset the value of n to -1 \n");
                        sem_post(c);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I don't get any output in my terminal.
To compile I used `gcc -pthread semaphore.c`. Where is the problem?

Expected Output is:

```
Child set value of n as 105
Parent reset the value of n to -1
Child set value of n as 207
Parent reset the value of n to -1
......
```

If any information required drop a comment below.

Comment: Works fine for me.  That being said, the parent and child each have their own copy of `n`.  Changes in one do not affect the other.

Comment: Did you try sem_t mutex; instead of the pointer?
Also you dont use sem_init(); and sem_close();

Comment: @dbush Really?? Doesn't work for me. I just checked. I don't get any output. Is it related to named semaphore? As it was already created before(when I first ran this program) but that time there was a bug in the below statement. Is it the case that the statement is discarded?

Comment: @Hamsa That could be it.  Run `ipcs -a` from the shell and see if those semaphores exist.  If they do, remove them with `ipcrm`.

Comment: @dbush I think I got it. The semaphores aren't getting created, `ipcs -a` doesn't list any semaphores.

Comment: @Jay-Pi I tried your suggestion too. It enters child process and prints `Child set value of n as 1804289383 ` only once and goes blank. I really don't know what is it's implications.

Comment: @Hamsa Can you update the code with my suggestions? If you want n to be shared memory, please also update n to reflect that.